# How to get data from a ListView in Dictionary format in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview

i've a `ListView` control like

[image: listview]

and a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<String,List<String>> MyDict
```

i need to fill the Dictionary with data in the `ListView`

So the Dictionary will be like

```
{ "S.No."  { "1","2","3" } }
{" A" {"A1", "", "" } }
{" B" {"B1", "B2", "" } }
{" C" {"C1", "C2", "C3" } }
```

using nested for loop we acn do this. But is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ToDictionary` method:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict =
    listView.Items
            .Cast<ListViewItem>()
            .ToDictionary(
                item => item.Text,
                item => item.SubItems
                            .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                            .Select(subItem => subItem.Text)
                            .ToList());
```

---

EDIT

OK, I misread the question... This should work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict =
    listView.Columns
            .Cast<ColumnHeader>()
            .ToDictionary(
                c => c.Text,
                c => listView.Items
                             .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .Select(i => i.SubItems[col.Index].Text)
                             .ToList());
```

(this works because the subitem at index 0 is actually the one that owns the other subitems)

Comment: It is possible that the texts under "SNo" come from `ListViewItem.Text` and texts under "A/B/C" come from `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem.Text`, which drives me crazy to write an one line linq query.

Comment: @ Thomas Levesque : Thanks for your answer. I need the Column Header as the key and Items as the value. Please see my Question